# Need to convert a list of numbers in Excel to all be 7 digits

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of a few thousand names and Employee ID numbers (EEID). The EEID in the list ranges between 3-7 digits. I need to convert all numbers that are less than 7 digits over to 7 digits by adding preceding zeros. Can it be done with formulas?

Comment: Do you want it to appear to have the extra zeroes a custom format of `0000000` will do that, or do you want the actual value, which would be a text string.  `=Text(A1,"0000000")`

Comment: The list includes several EEID that are less than 7 digits (139, 301271, etc) and I need those numbers to convert to 0000139, 0301271, etc.

Comment: Again, there are two ways of attacking this, one turns them into text that looks like numbers, the other only changes how those numbers are displayed.  You choose.

Comment: I suppose the text that looks like numbers - the ultimate result will be to get the 7-digit EEID uploaded into another system that doesn't differentiate between text/numbers.

Comment: Then my answer will do what you want.

Comment: It doesn't though. I still get EEIDs that are less than 7 digits, even when formatting for 7 digits.

Comment: See edit to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If all your EEID's are actual numbers use this formula:

```
=TEXT(trim(clean(A1)),"0000000")
```

If it is text or text that looks like numbers use:

```
=RIGHT("00000000" & trim(clean(A1)),7)
```

[image]

Comment: They are numbers but both fmlas above produce the same result of less than 7 digits.

Comment: You are going to need to provide some data, I am not getting those results

Comment: I have a screenshot but I'm not sure how to add it to a comment.

Comment: I figured out the issue - the system I am pulling the info from recently went through a huge conversion. Somewhere along the way, a space was added both before and after the EEID. If I remove the spaces, your first solution works. Problem is, I can only seem to find the preceding space - I have tried to search for the spaces (Ctrl +F & replace with nothing) but it only finds the first one.

Comment: @CarolAllen see edit, remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark if works.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the column, format cells, number, custom.  Choose the 0 type and put 7 zeros in the entry box and click okay.  All numbers entered will be 7 digits.

Comment: I know how to get future entries to be 7 digits but I am trying to convert existing entries to 7 digits by adding preceding zeroes to any that are less than 7 digits.